# Object doesn't support this property or method undefined in IE8 on call to indexOf defined array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, indexof

I have a site built in AngularJS that has been working brilliantly.  Unfortunately, our client requires the use of IE8.  Everything seems to work fine in the site on IE8, except for the fact that I'm getting an object doesn't support this property or methodundefined.  I spent all afternoon trying to figure out where the issue was, and I seem to have stumbled upon this bit of code, with the conditional of the if statement seemingly causing the issue:

```
var i = 0, len = $scope.data.length;
        for (; i < len; i++)
        {
            if ($scope.availableFilters.indexOf($scope.data[i].category) == -1)
            {
```

When I log out the variables, `$scope.availableFilters` is an empty array, `$scope.data.category` is a string, but when I log the `indexOf` call, it seems to throw the error, and not display the log I put after the log of the `indexOf` call.

Does anyone know why this would be?  Is this saying that `indexOf` isn't defined?  How could that be?

Comment: *"Does anyone know why this would be?"* Because IE8 doesn't support `indexOf` on arrays. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because it is not supported in that version of IE.

[Here is a polyfill that can be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 0):

[caniuse.com explains this well](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf). Array.prototype.indexOf isn't supported in IE8.

http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf

[There is a poly fill that you can use for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).